# When reading text file from file system, Spark still tries to connect to HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mesos, dcos

I just created a DC/OS cluster and am trying to run simple Spark task that reads data from `/mnt/mesos/sandbox`.

```
object SimpleApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("Simple Application")

    println("STARTING JOB!")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd = sc.textFile("file:///mnt/mesos/sandbox/foo")

    println(rdd.count)

    println("ENDING JOB!")
  }
}
```

And I'm deploying the app using

```
dcos spark run --submit-args='--conf spark.mesos.uris=https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foo --class SimpleApp https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar' --verbose
```

Unfortunately, task keeps failing with following exception

```
I0701 18:47:35.782994 30997 logging.cpp:188] INFO level logging started!
I0701 18:47:35.783197 30997 fetcher.cpp:424] Fetcher Info: {"cache_directory":"\/tmp\/mesos\/fetch\/slaves\/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2","items":[{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"extract":true,"value":"https:\/\/dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com\/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar"}},{"action":"BYPASS_CACHE","uri":{"extract":true,"value":"https:\/\/dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com\/foo"}}],"sandbox_directory":"\/var\/lib\/mesos\/slave\/slaves\/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2\/frameworks\/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002\/executors\/driver-20160701184530-0001\/runs\/67b94f34-a9d3-4662-bedc-8578381e9305"}
I0701 18:47:35.784752 30997 fetcher.cpp:379] Fetching URI 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar'
I0701 18:47:35.784791 30997 fetcher.cpp:250] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
I0701 18:47:35.784818 30997 fetcher.cpp:187] Fetching URI 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar'
I0701 18:47:35.784835 30997 fetcher.cpp:134] Downloading resource from 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2/frameworks/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002/executors/driver-20160701184530-0001/runs/67b94f34-a9d3-4662-bedc-8578381e9305/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar'
W0701 18:47:36.057448 30997 fetcher.cpp:272] Copying instead of extracting resource from URI with 'extract' flag, because it does not seem to be an archive: https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar
I0701 18:47:36.057673 30997 fetcher.cpp:456] Fetched 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2/frameworks/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002/executors/driver-20160701184530-0001/runs/67b94f34-a9d3-4662-bedc-8578381e9305/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar'
I0701 18:47:36.057696 30997 fetcher.cpp:379] Fetching URI 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foo'
I0701 18:47:36.057714 30997 fetcher.cpp:250] Fetching directly into the sandbox directory
I0701 18:47:36.057741 30997 fetcher.cpp:187] Fetching URI 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foo'
I0701 18:47:36.057770 30997 fetcher.cpp:134] Downloading resource from 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foo' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2/frameworks/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002/executors/driver-20160701184530-0001/runs/67b94f34-a9d3-4662-bedc-8578381e9305/foo'
W0701 18:47:36.114565 30997 fetcher.cpp:272] Copying instead of extracting resource from URI with 'extract' flag, because it does not seem to be an archive: https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foo
I0701 18:47:36.114600 30997 fetcher.cpp:456] Fetched 'https://dripit-spark.s3.amazonaws.com/foo' to '/var/lib/mesos/slave/slaves/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2/frameworks/c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002/executors/driver-20160701184530-0001/runs/67b94f34-a9d3-4662-bedc-8578381e9305/foo'
I0701 18:47:36.307576 31006 exec.cpp:143] Version: 0.28.1
I0701 18:47:36.310127 31022 exec.cpp:217] Executor registered on slave c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-S2
16/07/01 18:47:37 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.6.1
16/07/01 18:47:37 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/01 18:47:37 WARN SparkConf: 
SPARK_JAVA_OPTS was detected (set to '-Dspark.mesos.executor.docker.image=mesosphere/spark:1.0.0-1.6.1-2 ').
This is deprecated in Spark 1.0+.

Please instead use:
 - ./spark-submit with conf/spark-defaults.conf to set defaults for an application
 - ./spark-submit with --driver-java-options to set -X options for a driver
 - spark.executor.extraJavaOptions to set -X options for executors
 - SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS to set java options for standalone daemons (master or worker)

16/07/01 18:47:37 WARN SparkConf: Setting 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions' to '-Dspark.mesos.executor.docker.image=mesosphere/spark:1.0.0-1.6.1-2 ' as a work-around.
16/07/01 18:47:37 WARN SparkConf: Setting 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions' to '-Dspark.mesos.executor.docker.image=mesosphere/spark:1.0.0-1.6.1-2 ' as a work-around.
16/07/01 18:47:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/07/01 18:47:37 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/07/01 18:47:37 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with modify permissions: Set(root)
16/07/01 18:47:37 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 47358.
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@10.0.1.107:54467]
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriverActorSystem' on port 54467.
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-96092a9a-3164-4d65-8c0b-df5403abb056
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 511.1 MB
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://10.0.1.107:4040
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-37696e45-5e8b-4328-81e6-deec1f185d75/httpd-69184304-7ffd-4420-b020-5f8a1bafecbd
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Server: jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO AbstractConnector: Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:49074
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 49074.
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/mnt/mesos/sandbox/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar at http://10.0.1.107:49074/jars/foobar-assembly-1.0.jar with timestamp 1467398858626
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@712: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeeper C client 3.4.5
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@716: Client environment:host.name=ip-10-0-1-107.eu-west-1.compute.internal
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@723: Client environment:os.name=Linux
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@724: Client environment:os.arch=4.1.7-coreos-r1
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@725: Client environment:os.version=#2 SMP Thu Nov 5 02:10:23 UTC 2015
I0701 18:47:38.778355   103 sched.cpp:164] Version: 0.25.0
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@733: Client environment:user.name=(null)
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@741: Client environment:user.home=/root
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@753: Client environment:user.dir=/opt/spark/dist
2016-07-01 18:47:38,778:6(0x7f74cafc9700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@786: Initiating client connection, host=master.mesos:2181 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7f74d587c600 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd=<null> context=0x7f7540003f70 flags=0
2016-07-01 18:47:38,786:6(0x7f74c6ec0700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1703: initiated connection to server [10.0.7.83:2181]
2016-07-01 18:47:38,787:6(0x7f74c6ec0700):ZOO_INFO@check_events@1750: session establishment complete on server [10.0.7.83:2181], sessionId=0x155a57d07f60050, negotiated timeout=10000
I0701 18:47:38.788107    99 group.cpp:331] Group process (group(1)@10.0.1.107:35064) connected to ZooKeeper
I0701 18:47:38.788147    99 group.cpp:805] Syncing group operations: queue size (joins, cancels, datas) = (0, 0, 0)
I0701 18:47:38.788162    99 group.cpp:403] Trying to create path '/mesos' in ZooKeeper
I0701 18:47:38.789402    99 detector.cpp:156] Detected a new leader: (id='1')
I0701 18:47:38.789512    99 group.cpp:674] Trying to get '/mesos/json.info_0000000001' in ZooKeeper
I0701 18:47:38.790228    99 detector.cpp:481] A new leading master (UPID=master@10.0.7.83:5050) is detected
I0701 18:47:38.790293    99 sched.cpp:262] New master detected at master@10.0.7.83:5050
I0701 18:47:38.790473    99 sched.cpp:272] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
I0701 18:47:38.792147    97 sched.cpp:641] Framework registered with c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002-driver-20160701184530-0001
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Registered as framework ID c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002-driver-20160701184530-0001
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 38752.
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 38752
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.1.107:38752 with 511.1 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.1.107, 38752)
16/07/01 18:47:38 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 117.2 KB, free 117.2 KB)
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 12.6 KB, free 129.8 KB)
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.1.107:38752 (size: 12.6 KB, free: 511.1 MB)
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at SimpleApp.scala:13
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 4 is now TASK_RUNNING
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 2 is now TASK_RUNNING
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 0 is now TASK_RUNNING
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 1 is now TASK_RUNNING
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Mesos task 3 is now TASK_RUNNING
16/07/01 18:47:39 WARN DFSUtil: Namenode for hdfs remains unresolved for ID nn1.  Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
16/07/01 18:47:39 WARN DFSUtil: Namenode for hdfs remains unresolved for ID nn2.  Check your hdfs-site.xml file to ensure namenodes are configured properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: namenode1.hdfs.mesos
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUtil.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.getProxy(ConfiguredFailoverProxyProvider.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.<init>(RetryInvocationHandler.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.<init>(RetryInvocationHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryProxy.create(RetryProxy.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:524)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2397)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:427)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:400)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$33.apply(SparkContext.scala:1015)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1157)
    at SimpleApp$.main(SimpleApp.scala:15)
    at SimpleApp.main(SimpleApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:786)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: namenode1.hdfs.mesos
    ... 48 more
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/metrics/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/kill,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/api,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/static,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/threadDump,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/executors,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/environment,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/rdd,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/storage,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/pool,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/stage,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/stages,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/job,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs/json,null}
16/07/01 18:47:39 INFO ContextHandler: stopped o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler{/jobs,null}
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.1.107:4040
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: Asking each executor to shut down
I0701 18:47:40.051103   111 sched.cpp:1771] Asked to stop the driver
I0701 18:47:40.051283    96 sched.cpp:1040] Stopping framework 'c4bf7f81-1cf7-413a-b9be-8dc3b36137ee-0002-driver-20160701184530-0001'
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO CoarseMesosSchedulerBackend: driver.run() returned with code DRIVER_STOPPED
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Shutting down remote daemon.
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO RemoteActorRefProvider$RemotingTerminator: Remote daemon shut down; proceeding with flushing remote transports.
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-37696e45-5e8b-4328-81e6-deec1f185d75/httpd-69184304-7ffd-4420-b020-5f8a1bafecbd
16/07/01 18:47:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-37696e45-5e8b-4328-81e6-deec1f185d75
```

**Why is Spark trying to connect to HDFS although file type is explicitly set to `file://`?**

I thought that `sc.textFile("file:///")` doesn’t require HDFS setup.

Comment: This log only shows warnings, not errors. Can you post the complete log ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spark always use the Hadoop API to access a file, regardless of that file is local or in HDFS.

I think the problem is your Spark is inheriting an invalid HDFS configuration and hit this bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11227

You should try some workarounds in that ticket to see if it works for you:

- Use an older Spark < 1.5.0
- Disable HA in HDFS configuration.

Answer (score 3):

Spark will still use the hdfs to write the intermediate results of the stages (in your case, I guess the partial counts).

Comment: So there's no way to use Spark without HDFS if I need to read from local fs/s3 sources?

Comment: There are ways, but apparently you're loading Hadoop config into spark, since spark discovers your namenodes dns and all that stuff. I suppose you have something like export SPARK_CONF = HADOOP_CONF somewhere, which triggers everything.

Comment: I suppose the underlying spark executor docker image contains Hadoop config

Comment: If you use https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark/blob/master/Dockerfile , yes : `ENV YARN_CONF_DIR $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop`

Comment: Spark writes the intermediate results of a stages to local disk, not HDFS.

Comment: It's writing on HDFS in production right now here :D Not sure how you're set up though.

Comment: That's impossible. Spark literally doesn't have the code to write intermediate shuffle data to HDFS.